# Conversion of timestamp in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Below is the code I did in Pandas, but I need to do it in Dask.

```
df['converted'] = (df['timestamp'] - pd.Timestamp("1960-02-02").tz_localize(tz=df['timestamp][0].tz)) / pd.Timedelta('5s')
```

Here is the data frame `df`:

```
timestamp
2016-01-11 12:33:28.616000+00:00
2016-01-11 12:34:46.447000+00:00
2016-01-12 09:32:11.954000+00:00
2016-01-12 09:32:11.983000+00:00
2016-01-12 09:32:11.993000+00:00
```

I have no idea how to convert this because some functions are not available in DASK. All I can find is: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.to_datetime.html#to-datetime-tz-examples

Could you help me how can I do this in DASK?

Answer (score 1):

If your task is exactly as you describe, threre shouldn't be any problem to use `dask` here. All we have to do is subtract from DataFrame some constant value and divide the result by other one:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from io import StringIO

data = '''timestamp
2016-01-11 12:33:28.616000+00:00
2016-01-11 12:34:46.447000+00:00
2016-01-12 09:32:11.954000+00:00
2016-01-12 09:32:11.983000+00:00
2016-01-12 09:32:11.993000+00:00'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=[0])

x = pd.Timestamp("1960-02-02").tz_localize(tz=df['timestamp'][0].tz)
y = pd.Timedelta('5s')

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
output = (ddf - x) / y

df['converted'] = output.compute()
print(df)
```

Comment: @Coder Clerify the question if I missed something.

Comment: thing is the entire dataframe is a dask DF. I put just the example of pandas so people can see what i want to do.

Comment: @Coder Could you please post some code to produce an example of data you have to deal with?